# Is “Try it!” ever a constructive comment or answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

Over the past several years I've seen multiple comments (and the occasional answer) that suggest the OP should have answered the question simply by experimentation. For example, I’ve seen comments consisting of “Try it!” or “Have you tried it?”.

As a concrete example, consider the first comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17790127/what-is-meant-by-char-temp3/17790202), and its subsequent defense.

> Type it, compile it, debug it. Then you will know.

Is a recommendation that the OP “try it” ever constructive? [I've included my thoughts below, but I'd love to hear others.]

Comment: Try trying it? .

Comment: I *knew* someone would make a comment like that. :)

Comment: Seems as if the subsequent comments on that question not only handle the original "try it" comment, but also provide valuable additional guidance.

Comment: The subsequent comments include a back-and-forth argument about whether the "try it" comment was a valid way to find the answer.

Comment: Perhaps.  But my takeaway was that situations like the one that the OP described can be implementation-dependent, and so "trying it" might not be the best possible approach.

Comment: Exactly - and the OP wouldn't necessarily know this.

Comment: So what's the problem then?  Asked and answered.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - That ... "try it" was suggested as a way to answer the question, but as you observed, would not to answer the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with adding this as a comment, as long as you are careful to avoid doing it in a way that is needlessly rude.

Compare:

> Try compiling the code you have and seeing if it works. Then you will know the answer first-hand!

to

> Why are you wasting our time with this stupid question, you lazy bum? You could have just tried it yourself!

Guess which one I would flag?

My only reservation concerns languages like C and C++, where there is such a thing as undefined behavior. In these cases, trying something and seeing that it "works" is extremely misleading. It might work only in your specific environment, or it might not really work at all, it just *appears* to work. That's why people need to ask the question and receive expert answers. It's not just because their compiler is broken or because they are lazy.

I disagree strongly with Bill the Lizard here, who suggests that because the person asking the question doesn't specifically indicate that they are wondering if the behavior is well-defined, it is acceptable to recommend something that might invoke undefined behavior. This is just straight up a bad answer to a question, period. You cannot assume that people asking questions about something are experts in that field. Lots of new users to these languages don't even know about undefined behavior. It is our job to educate them, not mock them. Others who *do* know about it might think it is so obvious that they don't need to explicitly request solutions that are well-defined.

So sometimes, even a constructively-phrased "try it" comment is not useful, or can even promote a misleading impression. But that doesn't really make it *bad*. It just makes you look foolish to people who know better. If you can stomach that, go ahead. If you can't, well perhaps steer clear of [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b).

And, although it should go without being said, I'll say it anyway: "try it" is *never* acceptable as an answer.

Answer (score 28):

Yes, "try it" can be a constructive comment.  In this case, the question is:

> Normally in C++, character arrays are initialized in the following way,
>
> ```
> char example[5]="cat";
> ```
>
> What if you initialize it with `""` (just a double codes without spaces)?
> What will be the elements in the character array after initialization?

I think this is a classic case where "try it and see" *is* a constructive comment. The OP could have just run the modified code to see what would be in the array.

If the what the OP really wanted was an explanation *why* the elements of the array are what they are, that's the question they should have asked, after *trying it* to see what happened.

Comment: I agree with this answer, especially the bit about _why_. However sometimes 'try it' does come off as rude. I think 'What output did you get when trying to run it?" is generally better put.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I totally agree. That's a far better phrasing.

Comment: "What happened when you tried to run/debug/profile it?"  Really, just a friendly, sideways way of saying "You should have tried running/debugging/profiling it yourself first."

Comment: This holds true for the daily question of which is faster, X or Y?

Comment: I respectfully disagree that running the code provides an answer to the OP in this particular case. It is well-defined behavior, but the OP doesn't know that. Running the code isn't going to tell them.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer The question isn't whether "try it" is an answer.  the question is whether "try it" is helpful.  It can be helpful even if it's not the answer.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer My viewpoint tends to be that even if running the code won't in all cases yield a definite answer, doing so is what I consider putting forth a minimal effort.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer The OP doesn't need to know if it's well-defined behavior or not. That's not what they're asking. They only asked what's in the array when the code is modified. Running the code and looking in the array is the best way to find out.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - I strongly disagree. Nothing in the OP specifies interest or disinterest in whether the behavior is well-defined. And as programmers, we know that whether something is well-defined or not is important, because relying on undefined behavior is a source of risk, maintenance cost and defects.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer "Nothing in the OP specifies interest..." Then why would you assume there is any?  Answer the question that's being asked, not the one you're imagining.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - "... or disinterest." Both of us are interpreting the question. I find it more likely that the OP is interested in reliable behavior. However, even if the OP was not interested in well-defined behavior (seriously?), future readers may be.

Comment: @AndyThomas-Cramer I find it more likely that the OP is interested in the question they actually asked. I don't understand how you can read hidden meaning into a question and then *strongly disagree* that it's helpful to answer the actual question. Even if it only leads them to ask the question that they really had in mind, it's still helpful.

Comment: @BilltheLizard - Here's where we are. You're surprised that I'm assuming the question requests or merits a definitive answer. I'm surprised that you're assuming that it does not, and that you don't see that as also an assumption. We're beginning to repeat ourselves. I'm stepping out.

Answer (score 4):

If a question is asking what will happen when you do X, where X is an already complilable code sample, the question can very frequently be answered by simply trying it, as the comment you referenced indicated.

It doesn't always lead to an answer though.  Sometimes there are exceptional circumstances that prevent the test from being done (i.e. there was a question in which the code related to data sets so large running several iterative and experimental tests were prohibitively expensive).  Other times the results of the tests can be easily mis-interpreted, or can't be generalized.

However, even if the above issues (or others like them) exist, such a comment is helpful.  If possible, the OP should always try such tests themselves, even if they can't generalize their results or are curious if they interpret them correctly.  It's a way of [doing your homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in this context.  The question can then be edited to incorporate the results of their own tests, along with questions such as, "Even though the result of X is Y, can I always assume that to be the case; is my observation of this result correct and reliable?"  Such questions are of much higher quality.

If it's not possible for the OP to perform the test themselves, then it's very likely that the information will be useful to those answering the question.  Every single time I've hard "I can't" in response to "just try it" it explained something that should have been in the post to begin with.

Because of this, it's actually quite helpful to include "just try it" comments.  Sometimes they result in an answer, sometimes they don't.  They obviously aren't an answer themselves, so posting them *as an answer* is inappropriate (and should be flagged).  In the event that they don't result in the OP finding their own answer when they try it, what it does result in is a more specific, directed, and higher quality question.  A comment that results in a higher quality question is a good comment.

Comment: +1, thanks for a well-reasoned answer. That said, I'm beginning to think there may be a difference between asking whether the OP has tried it ("have you tried it?") to ensure the OP has done his or her homework, as you say -- versus just saying "try it", which could be read to imply that trying it will provide the answer.

Answer (score -9):

StackOverflow provides a community in which programmers of differing levels of skill can ask questions and get helpful answers. Those answers can be more helpful than quick experimentation.

A “try it” comment or answer can be *unhelpful, rude or misleading*.

It can be **unhelpful** because it does not provide an answer.

It can be **rude** if it implies frustration of being asked a question considered too simple for the listener to address.

It can be **misleading** because:

- The OP may not fully understand the issue, and may write the test incorrectly or incompletely.
- The results of a test could be specific to a particular compiler, version or platform.
- The results of a test could differ according to chance.
- The results of a test may not tell the whole story.
- Even when none of the above apply, the OP may not know this.

Comment: Or it might not be any of these things.  It might be entirely helpful.

Comment: "The OP may not fully understand the issue, and may write the test incorrectly or incompletely." The point is that we get the OP to *do something*. If they write it wrongly, all the more we can point out exactly where the OP went wrong in further comments or, better still, an answer.

Comment: The rest of your bullet points just don't hold water.

Comment: "It can be unhelpful because it does not provide an answer." That's presumably why it's a comment.

Comment: A "try it" comment cannot only be unhelpful, rude or misleading, it can also be right to the point. Which a comment should be.

Comment: I hear these comments, and the downvotes, but I'm leaving the answer. I think it's important to be polite and helpful to people asking a question. This doesn't mean that the OP should not also experiment.

Comment: @BilltheLizard The question is "Is “Try it!” ever a constructive comment *or answer*?" (and you actually just helped answer it, by pointing out that it can be a constructive comment, but not answer).

Comment: @RobertHarvey and everyone else assuming the answerer is saying that such a comment or answerer is *always* one of the three things he mentions:  He says "A “try it” comment or answer *can* be unhelpful, rude or misleading.", not "A “try it” comment or answer *is definitely one of* unhelpful, rude or misleading."

Comment: @A.M. Well, there's no effort to assert otherwise, so.

Comment: @A.M. That was my intent. I was expecting that others might answer the question with examples where it *was* useful. I'd been bugged by what I saw as sometimes rude and unhelpful, wanted to bring it up for discussion, and posted the thoughts I'd gathered over the past month.